# How to get the pull request number from predefined variable in azure build pipeline(CI)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I need PR number on which my CI kickoff.I am using System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber but it is showing empty string when my CI is running.

[image]

Write-Host "PR Number is:-" $env:System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber

**I am not running this CI through save and queue. Following the complete process of PR.**

Comment: Both are not working

Answer (score 5):

> How to get the pull request number from predefined variable in azure build pipeline(CI)

First, just like the document [System variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) state:

[image]

The variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber` is populated from **GitHub**. We should use the `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`.

So, we could use the syntax `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` to get the value:

```
Write-Host "PR ID is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

[image]

Besides, based on the [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) document

> When variables are turned into environment variables, variable names
>   become uppercase, and periods turn into underscores. For example,
>   **the variable any.variable becomes $ANY_VARIABLE**

So, if you get the environment variables `$env:System_PullRequest_PullRequestId` instead of `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)`

So, the scripts should be:

```
Write-Host "PR ID is:-" $env:System_PullRequest_PullRequestId
```

That is the reason why `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` not work for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

Write-Host "PR Number is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)

**EDIT**

as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber is populated from GitHub, are you sure you need this?

and System.PullRequest.PullRequestId:

> The ID of the pull request that caused this build. For example: 17.
>   (This variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git
>   PR affected by a branch policy.)

Comment: The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.After running the CI through proper commit and PR complete

Comment: strange, i have the exact same string: "Write-Host "PR Number is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)" which i posted above in my powershell v.2 Task and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

`$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy. The variable is also available only in Classic pipelines (not YAML), as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables).

You can extract the `PullRequestId` from:

```
"$(RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.*YOURARTIFACTNAME*.SOURCEBRANCH)"
```

Comment: Update: It appears that this variable is available in YAML pipelines (perhaps it was added later) and that the documentation [has been updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8610).

Answer (score 0):

You can get PR number via `System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber`.

For example I have a pull request on GitHub with this number: [image]

For this PR `Write-Host $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` returned 1030194803

And `Write-Host $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)` returned 63.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me only when running a build [triggered by a PR on GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers). If your build is being triggered outside of the PR context, for example after merging the PR, then this variable will not be available.

That happens because on Azure DevOps there is no way to trigger a build on PR merge: PR triggers on Azure DevOps only work when creating and updating a PR.

Therefore, on the example above, when you merge to master, what actually triggers the build is a [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

If your code is hosted on GitHub like in my case, you could create a workflow on GitHub to trigger on PR merge only, and do the logic you want there.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  merged-pr:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: | 
        echo This is the PR ${{ github.event.number }}
```

It is important to understand that, this pipeline will trigger on PR merge to master, whereas the CI triggers on Azure Pipelines will also trigger when you push to master - if configured that way. Therefore, when merging to master, the Azure DevOps pipeline and GitHub workflow will trigger at the same time.

If this is not ok, you could prevent that from happening by turning off the CI trigger on the pipeline, and triggering the build from the GitHub workflow. This can be achieved with this command:

```
az pipelines build queue --definition-name $azure_devops_pipeline_name --organization $azure_devops_organisation_url --project $project_name --branch master
```

In my case, I needed the PR number on the Azure DevOps pipeline, so I used a variable group for that. The logic I am running on the GitHub workflow, before triggering the pipeline, is precisely updating that number in a group variable. The command below should do precisely that.

```
az pipelines variable-group variable update --organization $azure_devops_organisation_url --project $project_name --group-id $azure_devops_variable_group_id --name $azure_devops_variable_name --value ${{ github.event.number }}
```